# Inquiry about a method of class Scanner

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have the following snippet which does  print out only "Indeed" instead of the whole thing:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+");      
    s = new Scanner("Indeed it's going to be the thing i am talking about");
   while(s.hasNext(pat)){

        System.out.println(s.next(pat));
```

I am thoroughly aware that there are other methods to obtain the output expected and so on. 
However I would like to know this particular case, why it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should pass the pattern in s.hasNext(pat) as parameter.

Comment: Edited: However I get out only "Indeed" and not the all tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Pattern` is `\\w+`, which matches: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, so:

```
while(s.hasNext(pat))
```

goes through once, since it matches: `Indeed`.

It does **not** match `it's` because of the `'`, so the loop terminates, and you only get `Indeed`.  If you remove the `'` it will work as planned.

To fix your code, you could do the following:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_0-9']+");
```

In case it's not apparent, I just added an `'` to your `Pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner.hasNext(String pattern)` returns true if the next token matches the pattern. In your case the first token is "Indeed" and it does not match pattern "."

Answer (score 0):

You actually need the method `findInLine`. Modify your code as:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+");      
Scanner s = new Scanner("Indeed it's going to be the thing i am talking about");
s.findInLine(pat);
while(s.hasNext())
        System.out.println(s.next());
```